# Why should I add the annotation @ApplicationContext for an ApplicationContext object?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

The Code A is from https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#6

And Code B is from https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#7

I find the annotation @ApplicationContext is added before appContext: Context in Code A, and none annotation is added before private val activity: FragmentActivity in Code B, why?

And more can I use Code C instead of Code A?

**Code A**

```
@Module
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): AppDatabase {
       ...
    }
  
}
```

**Code B**

```
class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val activity: FragmentActivity
) : AppNavigator {
    ...
}
```

**Code C**

```
@Module
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(appContext: ApplicationContext): AppDatabase {
       ...
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singletons live longer than Activities. Since Activity is a subtype of Context, if you pass it to a singleton that hangs onto the reference (just to use it as a Context), then that Activity has been leaked. The `@ApplicationContext` is an indicator that you should only pass the application Context as the parameter for the function. The application Context is constant for the lifetime of the app, so it is leak-proof.

The annotation is a way of documenting that you should not pass Activities as the context, but also Lint can warn you if you accidentally do it.

**Code C** doesn't make sense because you've made the parameter of type ApplicationContext, which is an annotation class and is not a Context subtype.